# Share a internet socket in specific port between multiple virtual machines

Tags: linux, sockets, virtualbox

I have the next scenario: a physical server with X cores (CentOS). In it, I am running 3 virtual machines using virtualBox (vm1, vm2 and vm3, each one with CentOS too).

Now in the physical machine, I have an internet socket binded in an specific port (says 1111). Is it possible for each vm to have access to that socket and read data from it? Maybe using a kind of port forwarding or changing the network configuration?

The idea is that each vm could access to the socket created for the physical machine for a kind of load distribution.
Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't read data from a listening socket at all, let alone in a shared way. The question doesn't make sense. What are you actually trying to accomplish here?

Comment: The idea is use an unique udp socket working in the real machine, and make the post processing of the receiving data in every virtual machine. Is a experiment to distribute load.